# Cant figure out how to sum up numbers with grep and awk when the numbers are quoted

Tags: windows, awk, grep

I have the output from a grep command `grep  -i "<Project" dottest\report.xml` which gives me this:

```
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="8" bdTotalFiles="8" checkedFiles="8" checkedLns="870" name="Common" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="228" totFiles="8" totLns="870" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="11" bdTotalFiles="11" checkedFiles="11" checkedLns="1440" name="Common.EW" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="263" totFiles="11" totLns="1440" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="10" bdTotalFiles="10" checkedFiles="10" checkedLns="552" name="Common.EW.Interfaces" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="119" totFiles="10" totLns="552" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="8" bdTotalFiles="8" checkedFiles="8" checkedLns="2740" name="Common.EW.Messages" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="976" totFiles="8" totLns="2740" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="6" bdTotalFiles="6" checkedFiles="6" checkedLns="2152" name="DataModel" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="922" totFiles="6" totLns="2152" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="5" bdTotalFiles="5" checkedFiles="5" checkedLns="745" name="ExternalMessages" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="507" totFiles="5" totLns="745" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="0" bdTotalFiles="0" checkedFiles="0" checkedLns="0" name="Resources" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="0" totFiles="7" totLns="996" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="3" bdTotalFiles="3" checkedFiles="3" checkedLns="725" name="ScriptReader" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="373" totFiles="3" totLns="725" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="7" bdTotalFiles="7" checkedFiles="7" checkedLns="1812" name="TestController" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="594" totFiles="7" totLns="1812" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="10" bdTotalFiles="10" checkedFiles="10" checkedLns="1232" name="TestControllerCli" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="88" totFiles="10" totLns="1232" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="16" bdTotalFiles="16" checkedFiles="16" checkedLns="1742" name="TestControllerGui" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="125" totFiles="16" totLns="1742" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="2" bdTotalFiles="2" checkedFiles="2" checkedLns="790" name="UnitTest_Common" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="162" totFiles="2" totLns="790" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="4" bdTotalFiles="4" checkedFiles="4" checkedLns="1629" name="UnitTest_DataModel" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="586" totFiles="4" totLns="1629" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="2" bdTotalFiles="2" checkedFiles="2" checkedLns="1479" name="UnitTest_ExternalMessages" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="591" totFiles="2" totLns="1479" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="9" bdTotalFiles="9" checkedFiles="9" checkedLns="1117" name="UnitTest_ScriptReader" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="29" totFiles="9" totLns="1117" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="9" bdTotalFiles="9" checkedFiles="9" checkedLns="1509" name="UnitTest_TestController" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="144" totFiles="9" totLns="1509" />
```

Now I want to add up some of the columns

I  have the following bash code that will do this (given a column number - in this case 3). But it only works if the column is a single whole number. In the output from my grep command I am getting numbers within quotes so I can't use this any more. I have no idea how to extract it.

Here is my current bash code:

```
grep  -i "<Project" dottest\report.xml | awk '{ SUM += $3; print $3 } END { print SUM }'
```

This yields:

```
bdTotalFiles="8"
bdTotalFiles="11"
bdTotalFiles="10"
bdTotalFiles="8"
bdTotalFiles="6"
bdTotalFiles="5"
bdTotalFiles="0"
bdTotalFiles="3"
bdTotalFiles="7"
bdTotalFiles="10"
bdTotalFiles="16"
bdTotalFiles="2"
bdTotalFiles="4"
bdTotalFiles="2"
bdTotalFiles="9"
bdTotalFiles="9"
0   (this is the sum)
```

So what I want to do is sum up all of the bdCheckedFiles or totErrs (for example).

I tried to add tr into this to replace the quotes:

```
D:\workspace > grep  -i "<Project" dottest\report.xml | tr '"' ' ' | awk '{ SUM += $3; print $3 } END { print SUM }'
tr: extra operand '|'
Try 'tr --help' for more information.
grep: write error: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

Yet if I remove the awk part it looks ok so I can't see the issue :(

```
D:\workspace > grep  -i "<Project" dottest\report.xml | tr '"' ' '
  <ProjectInformations>
  <Projects>
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 8  bdTotalFiles= 8  checkedFiles= 8  checkedLns= 870  name= Common  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 228  totFiles= 8  totLns= 870  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 11  bdTotalFiles= 11  checkedFiles= 11  checkedLns= 1440  name= Common.EW  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 263  totFiles= 11  totLns= 1440  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 10  bdTotalFiles= 10  checkedFiles= 10  checkedLns= 552  name= Common.EW.Interfaces  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 119  totFiles= 10  totLns= 552  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 8  bdTotalFiles= 8  checkedFiles= 8  checkedLns= 2740  name= Common.EW.Messages  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 976  totFiles= 8  totLns= 2740  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 6  bdTotalFiles= 6  checkedFiles= 6  checkedLns= 2152  name= DataModel  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 922  totFiles= 6  totLns= 2152  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 5  bdTotalFiles= 5  checkedFiles= 5  checkedLns= 745  name= ExternalMessages  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 507  totFiles= 5  totLns= 745  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 0  bdTotalFiles= 0  checkedFiles= 0  checkedLns= 0  name= Resources  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 0  totFiles= 7  totLns= 996  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 3  bdTotalFiles= 3  checkedFiles= 3  checkedLns= 725  name= ScriptReader  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 373  totFiles= 3  totLns= 725  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 7  bdTotalFiles= 7  checkedFiles= 7  checkedLns= 1812  name= TestController  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 594  totFiles= 7  totLns= 1812  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 10  bdTotalFiles= 10  checkedFiles= 10  checkedLns= 1232  name= TestControllerCli  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 88  totFiles= 10  totLns= 1232  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 16  bdTotalFiles= 16  checkedFiles= 16  checkedLns= 1742  name= TestControllerGui  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 125  totFiles= 16  totLns= 1742  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 2  bdTotalFiles= 2  checkedFiles= 2  checkedLns= 790  name= UnitTest_Common  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 162  totFiles= 2  totLns= 790  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 4  bdTotalFiles= 4  checkedFiles= 4  checkedLns= 1629  name= UnitTest_DataModel  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 586  totFiles= 4  totLns= 1629  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 2  bdTotalFiles= 2  checkedFiles= 2  checkedLns= 1479  name= UnitTest_ExternalMessages  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 591  totFiles= 2  totLns= 1479  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 9  bdTotalFiles= 9  checkedFiles= 9  checkedLns= 1117  name= UnitTest_ScriptReader  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 29  totFiles= 9  totLns= 1117  />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles= 9  bdTotalFiles= 9  checkedFiles= 9  checkedLns= 1509  name= UnitTest_TestController  qfixErrs= 0  suppErrs= 0  totErrs= 144  totFiles= 9  totLns= 1509  />
```

Comment: @Inian ah, sorry yes it is the sum of all the numbers in that column. So if we take bdTotalFiles then the output would be 110. (8 + 11 + 10 ... + 9)

Comment: You tagged your question with `bash` but your prompt `D:\workspace >` looks like something you'd see on Windows and your file name `dottest\report.xml` either contains a `\r` between `dottest` and `eport.xml` which would be weird or represents a Windows path of directory `dottest` and file `report.xml`. Are you REALLY on UNIX/bash or are you on Windows?

Comment: @EdMorton true, I am using linux commands on windows. But I want to use the linux/bash command set and not windows so I thought it more appropriate to tag with bash then with windows :)

Comment: That's a bit like asking for help replacing the windows in your house and then later telling us it's a submarine. YMMV wrt the benefits you get from the responses. Can you install cygwin?

Comment: @EdMorton I take your point. But I will also want to be able to use my script on linux too. I want it ideally to be OS agnostic in that it will use grep and awk etc... So putting "windows" specifically just seems wrong. Ill remove the bash tag and put windows in for correctness then.

Comment: If you can install cygwin then you CAN run the same scripts as-is on both UNIX (of which Linux is just one variation that seems to be getting a lot of press lately!) and Windows, otherwise you have to deal with the 2 different ways of quoting, etc. Just install cygwin, tag the question with "bash" and you'll be happy with both the answers and your use of the tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One liner**

```
awk 'match($0, /bdTotalFiles="[0-9]+"/){s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); print s; gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",s); total+=s}END{print "Sum",total}' file
```

**Explanation**

```
awk '
  match($0, /bdTotalFiles="[0-9]+"/){      # Search for match (bdTotalFiles="[0-9]+")  in current record/row ($0), if found do things inside braces
              s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)  # extract matched part from current record ($0) and assign to variable s
              print s                      # print extracted contents (contents of variable s) 
              gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",s)         # extract only numbers, remove anything except numeric values from extracted contents of variable s
              total+=s                     # sum up values
   }
   END{
     print "Sum",total                     # finally print sum
   }
   ' file                                  # Input file
```

**Input**

```
$ cat f
  <Project bdCheckedFiles="8" bdTotalFiles="8" checkedFiles="8" checkedLns="870" name="Common" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="228" totFiles="8" totLns="870" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="11" bdTotalFiles="11" checkedFiles="11" checkedLns="1440" name="Common.EW" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="263" totFiles="11" totLns="1440" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="10" bdTotalFiles="10" checkedFiles="10" checkedLns="552" name="Common.EW.Interfaces" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="119" totFiles="10" totLns="552" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="8" bdTotalFiles="8" checkedFiles="8" checkedLns="2740" name="Common.EW.Messages" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="976" totFiles="8" totLns="2740" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="6" bdTotalFiles="6" checkedFiles="6" checkedLns="2152" name="DataModel" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="922" totFiles="6" totLns="2152" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="5" bdTotalFiles="5" checkedFiles="5" checkedLns="745" name="ExternalMessages" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="507" totFiles="5" totLns="745" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="0" bdTotalFiles="0" checkedFiles="0" checkedLns="0" name="Resources" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="0" totFiles="7" totLns="996" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="3" bdTotalFiles="3" checkedFiles="3" checkedLns="725" name="ScriptReader" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="373" totFiles="3" totLns="725" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="7" bdTotalFiles="7" checkedFiles="7" checkedLns="1812" name="TestController" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="594" totFiles="7" totLns="1812" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="10" bdTotalFiles="10" checkedFiles="10" checkedLns="1232" name="TestControllerCli" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="88" totFiles="10" totLns="1232" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="16" bdTotalFiles="16" checkedFiles="16" checkedLns="1742" name="TestControllerGui" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="125" totFiles="16" totLns="1742" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="2" bdTotalFiles="2" checkedFiles="2" checkedLns="790" name="UnitTest_Common" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="162" totFiles="2" totLns="790" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="4" bdTotalFiles="4" checkedFiles="4" checkedLns="1629" name="UnitTest_DataModel" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="586" totFiles="4" totLns="1629" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="2" bdTotalFiles="2" checkedFiles="2" checkedLns="1479" name="UnitTest_ExternalMessages" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="591" totFiles="2" totLns="1479" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="9" bdTotalFiles="9" checkedFiles="9" checkedLns="1117" name="UnitTest_ScriptReader" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="29" totFiles="9" totLns="1117" />
     <Project bdCheckedFiles="9" bdTotalFiles="9" checkedFiles="9" checkedLns="1509" name="UnitTest_TestController" qfixErrs="0" suppErrs="0" totErrs="144" totFiles="9" totLns="1509" />
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'match($0, /bdTotalFiles="[0-9]+"/){s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); print s; gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",s); total+=s}END{print "Sum",total}' f
bdTotalFiles="8"
bdTotalFiles="11"
bdTotalFiles="10"
bdTotalFiles="8"
bdTotalFiles="6"
bdTotalFiles="5"
bdTotalFiles="0"
bdTotalFiles="3"
bdTotalFiles="7"
bdTotalFiles="10"
bdTotalFiles="16"
bdTotalFiles="2"
bdTotalFiles="4"
bdTotalFiles="2"
bdTotalFiles="9"
bdTotalFiles="9"
Sum 110
```

Comment: Thanks, nice solution and good explanation as well : ). Marked this one as the answer because of the extra explanation - but all the other answers are good too.

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally use an xml parser for this kind of thing.

Below is fragile solution that won't stand up if the order of the fields should change, but you can use the quotes `"` as a field separator with `awk -F \"`, instead of the default white space and retrieve the correct value:

```
grep  -i "<Project" dottest\report.xml | awk -F \" '{ SUM += $4; print $3$4 } END { print SUM }'
```

Outputs:

```
 bdTotalFiles=8
 bdTotalFiles=11
 bdTotalFiles=10
 bdTotalFiles=8
 bdTotalFiles=6
 bdTotalFiles=5
 bdTotalFiles=0
 bdTotalFiles=3
 bdTotalFiles=7
 bdTotalFiles=10
 bdTotalFiles=16
 bdTotalFiles=2
 bdTotalFiles=4
 bdTotalFiles=2
 bdTotalFiles=9
 bdTotalFiles=9
110
```

Comment: thankyou, nice fix : )... don't want a heavy weight xml parser. Its a small script and I want it to fail if the syntax changes in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Why run grep and awk?

```
awk '/Projects/ { n=match($0, /bdTotalFiles="([[:digit:]]+)"/, r); sum +=r[1]; } END { print sum; }'
```

This only runs awk. The summing takes place if the line has the string Projects in it, then finds the number after the bdTotalFiles= string. If your quotes are optional you can put a ? into the regex after the "s. And it is easy to extend to multiple columns. Not tested.

Comment: Thanks! - as to "why run grep and awk", because I didn't know better, but I do now : )